# Im trying to find out what is allowing users to withdraw twice the amount or more, of what is in their accounts

Tags: javascript, php

I have a section of my site that allows users to withdraw dogecoins in their accounts to another wallet. Its newly launched today. Today I noticed a user depositing and withdrawing multiple times in a row. The withdrawals were always double the deposits.

Luckily I have a reserve  in case something like this happened, and no user accounts will be affected.

I checked the dogechain, and everything seems good there. No transaction malleability, and the amounts were always what was withdrawn. The problem is, by the time it hit the dogechain, it was already doubled, which pretty much means its my site that is allowing it to happen.

The scope of what is going on, is currently outside of what I know of php.

When the user withdraws, they click a button which opens a small withdraw window:

Button code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:return withdraw();" class="withdraw">Withdraw</a></div>
```

Background javascript withdraw() function:

```
function _requestWithdraw(amount,valid) {
  $.ajax({
    'url': './content/ajax/withdraw.php?valid_addr='+valid+'&amount='+amount+'&_unique=<?php echo $unique; ?>',
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function(data) {
      _message='<br><small>';
      if (data['error']=='yes') {           
        if (data['content']==0) _message+='Entered <?php echo $settings['currency_sign']; ?> address is not valid! Please, check the address and try again.';
        else if (data['content']==1) _message+='Entered amount is not valid. You probably does not have enough balance for this.';            
      }
      else {
        _message+='Amount has been successfuly sended!<br>Transaction ID: '+data['content'];
        refreshbalance();
      }
      _message+='<br><br><a href="#" class="microbuttons" onclick="javascript:_renewWithdraw();return false;">Back</a>';
      $("#_withdraw_content").html(_message);           
    }
  });
}
var withdrawing;
function withdraw() {
  withdrawing=false;
  $.msgBox({
    title:"Withdraw Funds",
    content:"<div id=\"_withdraw_content\"><br><small>Enter valid <?php echo $settings['currency_sign']; ?> address:</small><br><input id=\"w_valid_ltc\" type='text' class='l' style='width: 100%;'><br><br><small>Enter amount to be paid-out:</small><br><input id=\"w_amount\" type='text' class='l' style='width: 100px; text-align: center;'><br><br><small><small>Min. value: <b>0.001</b> <?php echo $settings['currency_sign']; ?><br>We charge a fee <b>0.0002</b> <?php echo $settings['currency_sign']; ?> for each withdrawal.</small></small></div>",
    type:"info",
    opacity:0.8,
    buttons: [{ value: "Withdraw" }, { value: "Cancel" }],
    success: function(button) {
      if (button=="Withdraw" && withdrawing==false) {
        w_amount=$("input#w_amount").val();
        w_valid=$("input#w_valid_ltc").val();
        if (w_amount!='' && w_valid!='') {
          $("#_withdraw_content").html('<div style=\"height: 50px;\"></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="content/images/ajax_loader.gif">');
          withdrawing=true;
          _requestWithdraw(w_amount,w_valid);
        }
        else {
          alert('One of required fields stayed empty!');
        }
      }
    }
  });      
  return false;
}
```

They input the amount they want to withdraw, and what address to send it too.

The background happenings are as follows:

The escaping function:

```
function prot($hodnota,$max_delka=0) {
  $text=mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($hodnota));
  if ($max_delka!=0)  $vystup=substr($text,0,$max_delka);
  else  $vystup=$text;
  return $vystup;
}
```

This portion is wallet.php, it is called by the withdraw() function window that pops up on the front end:

```
<?php

$included=true;
include '../../inc/db-conf.php';
include '../../inc/wallet_driver.php';
$wallet=new jsonRPCClient($driver_login);
include '../../inc/functions.php';

if (empty($_GET['amount']) || empty($_GET['valid_addr']) || empty($_GET['_unique']) || mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `sellers` WHERE `hash`='".prot($_GET['_unique'])."' LIMIT 1"))==0) exit();

$seller=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`balance` FROM `sellers` WHERE `hash`='".prot($_GET['_unique'])."' LIMIT 1"));

$validate=$wallet->validateaddress($_GET['valid_addr']);
if ($validate['isvalid']==false) {
  $error='yes';
  $con=0;
}
else {
  if (!is_numeric($_GET['amount']) || (double)$_GET['amount']>$seller['balance'] || (double)$_GET['amount']<0.001) {
    $error='yes';
    $con=1;
  }
  else {
    $amount=(double)$_GET['amount']-0.0002;
    $txid=$wallet->sendfrom('',$_GET['valid_addr'],$amount);
    mysql_query("UPDATE `sellers` SET `balance`=`balance`-".prot($_GET['amount'])." WHERE `id`=$seller[id] LIMIT 1");
    $error='no';
    $con=$txid;
  }
}
$return=array(
  'error' => $error,
  'content' => $con
);

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Thes following function is called by the function _renewWithdraw() (I think) function after they have input their wallet address and amount of doegcoins and hit "Withdraw"

```
function refreshbalance() {
  $("#balance_").html('<img src="content/images/alternative_loader.gif">');
  $.ajax({
    'url': './content/ajax/request_balance.php?_unique=<?php echo $unique; ?>',
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function(data) {
      $("#balance_").html(data['balance']);
    }
  });
  return false;
```

This is the page that the refreshbalance function calls:

```
<?php

$included=true;
include '../../inc/db-conf.php';
include '../../inc/functions.php';

if (empty($_GET['_unique']) || mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `sellers` WHERE `hash`='".prot($_GET['_unique'])."' LIMIT 1"))==0) exit();
$balance=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `balance` FROM `sellers` WHERE `hash`='".prot($_GET['_unique'])."' LIMIT 1"));
$balance_=rtrim(rtrim(sprintf("%0.12f",$balance['balance']),'0'),'.');
$return=array('balance' => $balance_);
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Can some please help me with figuring out how, they are withdrawing double their balance, and how to stop it. I dont have a developer at the moment and Im pretty sure this is completely out of my knowledge to fix in a timely manner.

Im guessing either my site is allowing multiple instances to be ran at the same time, and isnt checking the balance in the right order, to prevent that.

Most importantly, im not even sure what the right question to ask is. Im hoping someone will look at the code, and see a better way of doing it.

Comment: As a side note, Im willing to pay in bitcoin if someone can either rewrite the code to be more updated and fix the problem, or to just fix the issue of users withdrawing double their site balance.

Comment: First, please upgrade to `mysqli_*` or PDO since `mysql_*` is deprecated and can easily be injected. Secondly, this `'&_unique=jxWpyAe3uSJ2nag...'`, guessing that's a test value, based on this value you are fetching the `id` and `balance`. That's totally **insecure!**. If an user comes to know of the hash of another user with more balance, they can enter that data in your ajax parameter and get lots more balance than they are allowed to. What you should ideally be doing is, generate this `_unique` value at server side and save it into session, and then use that against the `hash` column.

Comment: I think user might clicked twice or somehow managed to initiate 2 ajax request. Which behaves as 2 different threads simultaneously trying to withdraw (Implement a locking mechanism on per user basis). 
You should first execute the query and if it is successfully according to your conditions then send wallet form.

Comment: Ive edited the above entry. The 'unique=jxw... part I must have grabbed from a "Show Source code" by accident. Is the updated code, something along the lines of correct?

Comment: @Net, I dont really know much about coding. Is there an easy way to implement locking and a query per user?

Comment: @Cheezeburger hopefully I can find someone who is willing to work for bitcoin to update the site, once this pressing issue is resolved.

Comment: Why did you even start to implement something like this if you lack the experience in coding?

Comment: @user14872 So you are getting the value from PHP. In that case, what I meant was, do not pass it through AJAX. Save that into a SESSION variable and use that SESSION variable in your query.

Comment: @CBroe History is filled with people who start a project they know very little about.

If experience is the only factor, then why start any site unless you are a fully qualified phd or whatever the highest magic the gathering rank is???

Comment: @Cheezburger I broke down and hired someone to do it. im reading up on php right now. Im going to do my best to not be in this situation again.

Comment: @user14872 Good luck! Feel free to ask questions here if you need more advice from the community.

Comment: @James - please do not delete your question content like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think user might have clicked twice or somehow managed to initiate 2 ajax request. Which behaves as 2 different threads simultaneously trying to withdraw (Implement a locking mechanism on per user basis). You should first execute the query and if it is successfully according to your conditions then send wallet form.

**Workaround**

The quickest way for you might be switch `$wallet->sendfrom` and `mysql_query`. positions. 
Let say user has 100$ in account and he made a transaction of 100$ (due to bug or some thing), It becomes 2 Ajax request.
First thread checks the user current balance is 100$, its enough balance process and calls the send wallet information (let say it take 30 second).
Meanwhile another thread comes in, it also check the current balance (100$ which is the same as of the first thread read, and haven't returned yet from `$wallet->sendfrom`). it will also send wallet and on `return` both with will execute the `update sql script`.

```
$txid=$wallet->sendfrom('',$_GET['valid_addr'],$amount);
mysql_query("UPDATE `sellers` SET `balance`=`balance`-".prot($_GET['amount'])." WHERE `id`=$seller[id] LIMIT 1");
```

Switching these lines will reduce the chance of error. (You have to implement some locking mechanism for 100% surety).

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `sellers` SET `balance`=`balance`-".prot($_GET['amount'])." WHERE `id`=$seller[id] LIMIT 1");
$txid=$wallet->sendfrom('',$_GET['valid_addr'],$amount);
```

Also try to `disable` the button/Link which initiate the `withdraw` process as soon as user enters in this mode, and `renable` it once `ajax` request is successful. It will reduce the chance of error from front end.

**Updated :**

**Simulate locking with session variable**
I believe PHP does not support a nice and clean way for thread safety. So here is workaround using session variable as we require locking per user basis.(People do use flock for similar kind of functionality)

Separate session variables are created for each user `$_SESSION["variable_name"]`, so we can use that if the current user transaction is locked or not.

1. First step would be to check if `$_SESSION["isLocked"]` is true or not, (it could be not set if user comes first time). If its true, Means a transaction is already in progress and exit the script with some error.
2. Secondly if its not set or contains false (Means no transaction in progress) so first step would be to assign true. and processed with processing of withdraw.
3. Finally when script is done with the all the processing set this session variable to false.

Here is sample code for above steps.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION["isLocked"]) && $_SESSION["isLocked"] === true) {
    echo "A transaction is already in progress.";
    exit();
}
else {

    //hold the lock
    $_SESSION["isLocked"] = true;
    $_SESSION["lock_time"] =  time(); //current time (can be used to unlock the current user session after some time in case of error/bugg or some thing)

    //perform wallet api calls
    echo "Processing data";
    //you must check if above call is success full
        //then run update query for updating the balance.

    //release the lock
    $_SESSION["isLocked"] = false;
}
```

**Please note:** Its not thread safety but a way to reduce the chances of errors.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. i ended up highering someone to go through the code and update everything to mysqli while he is at it. Hopefully I can run the site safely while learning php. Afterall, its not me Im trying to protect, its the dogecoin community and my users. I will definitely try this in case he runs into any problems. Thanks again.Btw the button does actually do that. Im guessing the guy is copying the url into multiple browsers and hitting them at the same time, or something similar.

Comment: One question, when you say locking mechanism... what type? how do I implement something that is local to each user while allowing the others to do their withdrawals. From what I read of flock(), it locks actual txt files or similar.

Comment: @James I have explained a way to simulate locking with session variables, please have a look on updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Net, while everyone else was intent on directing me several places, you actually helped and I appreciate that very much. I will give it a shot. Thanks again.